# Find number of permutations with length N such that sum of all elements will be M and all elements will be lower or equal to K

Tags: combinatorics

As the title says, I need formula for finding number of permutations which are in length N and sum of their elements is M and all elements are lower than K

Here is one example

N = 2, M = 5, K=3

There are 2 permutations (2,3), (3,2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $N$ into $M$ parts of at most $K$.You want the A-restricted compositions to get the at most $K$ restriction.  Some references are given.